# What is the best way to ensure the main thread is blocked while a background thread is processing?

Tags: ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

Consider the following case:

```
Main Thread -----UIView info \ --------------------------------------- / Button Updated ------
                              \ (Some Event)                          / (Some Event)
                               \                                     /
BG Thread ---------------------Validate UIView info-----Update Button------------------------
```

1. On the main thread, a UIView is present
2. UIView makes a dispatch call is made to a background thread
3. In the BG Thread, the UIView's info is validated.
4. BG Thread makes a dispatch call to a UIButton on the main thread to update it.

My question is - notice how there is a gap between UIView info and the UIButton which means that the app could technically be updated during this time. How can I possible stop this gap? Essentially, from the BG thread, block the Main Thread till the call comes back?

Comment: As others said, you never “block” the main thread. Where necessary, while the async process is underway, you can temporarily (a) disable user interaction; and/or (b) show some visual indication that the async process is underway, and re-enable when it’s done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot and must never block the main thread. If you do, the interface will freeze and, if the blockage lasts too long, the WatchDog process will kill your app dead before the user's very eyes.

You can give the user a sense that something is going on, and discourage the user from doing anything, by, say, turning off user interaction and putting up a spinner. But in general, yes, multithreading is hard; you must be prepared for the possibility that you will come back onto the main thread when the app has changed state.

Comment: Thanks @matt - really appreciate you looking at this question. The delay will never be over a second. This is more for internal validation.

Comment: In that case the temporary interface displaying a spinner sounds like a good solution. The purpose of my answer is just to discourage you from supposing you can somehow guarantee the state of the app when you leave the main thread and return to it later. You can never do that; your app is _event-driven_, which means stuff is free to happen whenever your main thread code is not running. One must learn to think in those terms.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than block a main thread, disable user input controls in your view until the validation is complete, then re-enable them.

It would also make sense to add an activity indicator with hidesWhenStopped set to true; it will show the user that there's background work in progress if you start it when the background work starts, and stop it when validation is complete.

If there's ever a chance the background process could hang or take longer, e.g. if it's making a network request, you might show/enable a cancel button and a way to terminate it.

Showing activity indicator and possibly providing a cancel button both require that the main thread keep running, so definitely don't block it!

Answer (score 1):

Your button should not be updated in the background. You should always modify `UIKit` components on the main thread.

You should also never block the main thread, what you're looking for is the show the user an indication that a background process is active. 'UIActivityIndicatorView' might be a good thing to show the user, you could also disable user interaction on the view to prevent the user from touching anything if it's critical for them to wait until the operation is complete but not recommended.

Comment: The delay is never for over a second - it's mostly for internal processing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should never block the main thread and update UI only on main thread.

That said - show a spinner / activity indicator while busy on the background.

Think carefully about the UI and e.g. present something so the user can not change something while you are busy with e.g. dialog or popover or something like that.

In practise this often becomes more a question of UX than blocking.